# How do I end a string in '<Carriage Return> <Line Feed>'?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm supposed to compare two strings in 8086 assembly, without using string instructions. So far so good. I managed to find something close to this, but the assignment also mentions having to end the strings in   = (0x0d,0x0a). I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and I'm not sure if the code I have already does this.

I've tried searching a bit on the internet and through some documentation, but either my level of knowledge is too low or I simply haven't found a proper explanation.

Here is the code:

```
  DATA SEGMENT
        STR1 DB "ENTER FIRST STRING HERE ->$"
        STR2 DB "ENTER SECOND STRING HERE ->$"
        STR11 DB "FIRST" 13, 10 "STRING : ->$"
        STR22 DB "SECOND STRING: ->$"

        INSTR1 DB 20 DUP("$")
        INSTR2 DB 20 DUP("$")
        NEWLINE DB 10,13,"$"
        N DB ?
        S DB ?
        MSG1 DB "BOTH STRING ARE SAME$"
        MSG2 DB "BOTH STRING ARE DIFFERENT$"

  DATA ENDS

  CODE SEGMENT

        ASSUME DS:DATA,CS:CODE
  START:

        MOV AX,DATA
        MOV DS,AX

        LEA SI,INSTR1
        LEA DI,INSTR2

  ;GET STRING
        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,STR1
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH
        MOV DX,SI
        INT 21H


        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,STR2
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,0AH
        MOV DX,DI
        INT 21H


        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H


  ;PRINT THE STRING

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,STR11
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,INSTR1+2
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,STR22
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,INSTR2+2
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

  ;STRING COMPARISON
        MOV BX,00

        MOV BL,INSTR1+1
        MOV BH,INSTR2+1

        CMP BL,BH
        JNE L1

        ADD SI,2
        ADD DI,2

      L2:MOV BL,BYTE PTR[SI]
        CMP BYTE PTR[DI],BL
        JNE L1
        INC SI
        INC DI
        CMP BYTE PTR[DI],"$"
        JNE L2

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,MSG1
        INT 21H

        JMP L5

      L1:MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,MSG2
        INT 21H



     L5:
        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H


  CODE ENDS
  END START
```

Comment: First, rethink all instructions which contain `INSTR1+...` and replace them by using `SI` and `DI` as an index base instead. You did set `SI` and `DI` with `LEA SI,INSTR1 ; LEA DI,INSTR2` for a reason... and the reason is you need them for indexing. IIRC `SI` and `DI` are also preserved on `INT 21h` calls, so they are a good choice as string pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db "foo", 13, 10, "$"`

You already have a Newline with `db 10,13, "$"`.

That's `0xa, 0xd` (opposite of the usual DOS order, but same effect if they're processed separately and moving the cursor vertically and horizontally.)